# How do I create an extended message ID in CAPL?

Tags: capl, messageid

CAPL does accept message definitions like the following

*message 100x mymsg*

It does not however accept long message IDs, which is the case of extended payloads. In other words, this is what I would like to do (and CAPL does not accept):

*message 18FEF889x mymsg*

I know there is the function mkExtId(), though I haven't still figured out how it works. I tried something like

*message 18FEF889x mymsg*

*mkExtId(mymsg.id)*

but it still doesn't work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First declare a message without ID

   > message *ExtMsg;  // Declaration without Id
2. Use CAPl Function mkExtId() to return an extended ID
3. assign that id to the message.

> ```
> variables
> {
>   timer T1 = 1;
>   message 0x100 stdMsg;
>   dword ext_id ;
>   message *ExtMsg;  // Declaration without Id
> }
>
> on start
> {
>   setTimer(T1,1);
>   ext_id = mkExtId(0x34444);
>   ExtMsg.id = ext_id;
>   ExtMsg.dlc = 2;
> }
>
> on Timer T1
> {
>  ExtMsg.byte(0) = 99;
>  stdMsg.stdSignal =2;
>  output(stdMsg);
>  output(ExtMsg);
>  setTimer(T1,1);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply declare the message in this way:

```
message 0x114455x msg;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `mkExtId` returns the extended id, which then you assing to the `id` if the message, here an example:

This function sets the extended id of the message passed:

```
void setExtId(dword x_id, message* m)
{
  dword ext_id;
  ext_id = mkExtId(0x1FFFFFFF);
  m.id = mkExtId(x_id);
  if(m.id == ext_id)
  {
    write("some stuff");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still I can't upvote you since I don't have 15 votes!

Comment: No problem. Did it work? I had that snippet, but I was not able to fully test it.